# Keeping Regex search to one line

Tags: regex

I used Wget to scrape a site for migrating to new platform.  I am trying to clean up the pages and remove all the viewstate code in them.   I am using the following regex expression to do this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" value=.*/>
```

This works in programs like dreamweaver.  I like to use another application called Wild Edit which is extremely fast for search and replace for large number of files.  When I use that same expression it will match to the last `/>` on the page remove alot of good code.   I have also tried `<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" value=.*/>$`  with same results.

How would I constrain this to keep it to the first match of />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" value=.*?/>
```

The `?`, if it's supported makes the search ungreedy so it will only match until the *first* `/>` rather than the last.

If that doesn't work, your best bet may be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" value=[^/]+/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex is being too greedy. Try this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" value=.*?/>
```

By default, the regex engine tries to make as large of a match as possible. For example, the regular expression `a.*z` will match `az (some other middle stuff) az` as one big match, since, well, it *does* start with `a` and end with `z`.

The `?` modifier tells the regular expression engine to, rather than be greedy, be lazy: instead of grabbing the *largest* possible match, grab the *smallest*. In the previous example, the regex `a.*?z` will just match the 2 `az` substrings, because it's being lazy: once it sees the `z`, it stops.